# how to get the list of files from the directory one by one into a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am new to Batch script,
by using the following code

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for %%x in (D:\all_files\*.csv) do set LIST=!LIST! %%x
set LIST=%LIST:~1%
echo %LIST%
```

i am getting the filenames with directory and also with a Paragraph 
but i need file names alone one by one like below into a Variable of %LIST%

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

can any one please help us

Comment: sounds like a [X-Y-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need *all* of them in *one* variable? What do you want to do with that variable later?

Comment: if i get one by one into a variable , i am going to check the below conditions

 if "%List%"=="file1.csv" (
 GOTO 1.bat 
) 
 if "%List%"=="file2.csv" (
 GOTO 2.bat 
) else (
GOTO 3.bat
)

Comment: How could `%List%` be equal to `file1.csv`, when you concatenated *all* files into `%List%` before? Rethink your logic.

Comment: Other wise i have to write like below
@echo off
set local
:function1
echo Please wait files are prosessing...
timeout /t 10

IF EXIST C:\file1.csv (
GOTO ResultTrue1
) else (
GOTO function1
)

:ResultTrue1
IF EXIST C:\file2.csv (
GOTO ResultTrue2
) else (
GOTO function1
)
exit /b 0

:ResultTrue2
call process1.bat
exit /b 0

like that i have to check 10 files
it's very lengthy

so that's why i am looking in to a variable.

Comment: so you want to check if all `csv` files in `D:\all_files` are also present in `C:\ `? And if they are, `call process1.bat`?

Comment: yes
one directory it self fine not for  other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, I got your intentions right.
Instead of a variable, just loop over output of `dir /b`

```
:loop
echo still waiting...
timeout /t 10
set "ok=yes"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "D:\all_files\*.csv"') do (
  if not exist "C:\%%a" set "ok=no"
)
if "%ok%" == "no" goto :loop
echo all there...
call process1.bat
```

Comment: thank you so much
'dir /b "D:\all_files\*.csv"' here you are checking all .csv files is there in the directory right ?
please help me , how we can check file1.csv and file2.csv is there in the directory ore not then only we need to call process1.bat

Comment: I  Got it
we need to check 

if not exist "C:\file1.csv" set "ok=no"

Thank you Sooooo Much

Comment: If it isn't "all files that are here", but some predefined names, iterate over a list instead: "for %%a in ("file1.txt" "file2.txt" ... ) do ...